# How much splash range does the RPG have in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Sometimes I feel like I am super far away from the RPG blast but still get hit. What range would I have to be, away from the explosion, to take 0 damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RPG has a one-square damage range. When you build 4 walls around you, the space in between is called a square, which there are thousands of on the map. If someone shoots an RPG and it lands exactly a square away from you, it will deal damage - but if you moved a tiny bit back before, you would be alive. The same applies to grenades, boogie bombs, smoke grenades and impulse grenades. If the RPG hits in the corner of one square, like in the diagram below, it will damage 4 different squares.

Red represents highest damage - usually between 140 to 240.

Orange represents normal damage - usually between 80 and 140.

Yellow represents low damage - usually between 20 and 80.

The  black dot under the player shows where they are, and the RPG image shows where the blast hit.

[image: explanation picture]

As you can see, 4 squares around the blast are affected, and if you are a square away from the blast you may still get fairly high damage, leading you to die.

Hope this helped.

Comment: So if you jump right as the rocket hits near you can you potentially take less damage?

Comment: @FlamingThunder certainly. something that helps greatly is using an impulse grenade to jump further back - but you could also build a wall, which can absorb the damage from a rocket- if someone is spamming them at you, keep building walls, and the rockets wont deal damage to someone behind them - only the walls

Answer (score -3):

I watched a replay of me getting killed by a rocket and it was two "blocks" away from me and it killed me when I had 120 hp

Comment: Welcome and thanks for contributing. I'm sure the OP will find your input helpful, but it may have been better to post this as a comment, since this doesn't answer the question completely. You may need to [wait to comment until you have sufficient reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Until then, keep on asking and answering good questions!